# XML Comments not appearing in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, web-services, comments, xml-comments

I have a WCF service and commenting my operation contracts as below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Call to topup a card.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="topUp">The TopUp object which specifies the card to topup.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a boolean indicating whether call has finished successfully.          </returns>
    [OperationContract]
    bool UploadTopUp(TopUp topUp);
```

However the XML comments I am putting in the 3 forward slashes as above /// do not appear in the tooltips in my client application that consumes it, is this standard WCF/web service functionality? Will they never appear? OR is there a way to make them appear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xml Doc comments are generally not integrated into the generated WSDL for a WCF service. This information is usually only available when the appropriate xml documentation file is co-located with a directly referenced assembly.

The only information that is included in a generated WSDL (or metadata provided by a MEX endpoint) are the properties of the contract attributes themselves. Check the documentation for the following:

- [ServiceContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx)
- [OperationContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx)
- [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)
- [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx)
- [MessageContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.aspx)
- [MessageHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageheaderattribute.aspx)
- [MessageBodyMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagebodymemberattribute.aspx)
- [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx)

Comment: THanks, Is there any way to colocate the XML with the client referencing it? Force it somehow?

Comment: The XML is only used if it directly matches the assembly that generated it. You could drop it in the bin folder of your client, but it will not do anything. You may be able to rename the file to match the .dll that contains the client WCF proxy. The proxy types will be in different namespaces, and they will not directly match the source types, so there are no guarantees.

Comment: This is a real shame... I wonder if there's any way to extend the process that generates the Reference.cs to also pull over the comments.