# The XML comments for methods appears in .wsdl file but not in WCF client side code

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Comments not appearing in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239327/xml-comments-not-appearing-in-wcf-service)

Thanks to WCFExtras, the XML comments for WCF methods appears in generated .wsdl file. Now the problem is that the XML comments doesn't appear when I call a method in client side code (proxy).

Does someone knows how to make xml comments appear in client side code, or a method to extract the comments from .wsdl file and associate with client code?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is not a duplicate because I managed to bring those XML Comments in WSDL and I have to make one step further: to appear in proxy tooltips code :D.

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate because it explains why you're not going to get those comments, or any WSDL documentation, into the proxy, unless you generate the proxy yourself.